# Finding Unequal Rows in Two Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am doing a left join query to compare the two tables for any values that do not equal each other on f9 and sumoff6 columns ONLY if the F1 columns are the same. If they are different i would like to subtract them.

The results I am getting show equal values that are already on both tables. I need for f1 columns to match on both tables but if their values on the sumoff6 and f9 columns do not match then display them and subtract them. F1 is unique on both tables. Keeep in mind though that there may be more rows in the statement table. I am using MS Access SQL view.

Query

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9
FROM statement 
LEFT JOIN allocation_final ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1]
WHERE [allocation_final].sumoff6 <> statement.f9
```

Statement table:

```
f1     f9
-----------------
1      135.58
2      166.30
3       40.22 
4       86.46
5      170.33
6       96.40
```

allocation_final:

```
f1     SumOff6
--------------
1      135.58
2      166.30
3       40.00
4       86.46
5      170.33
6       40.22 
7       22.40
8       70.00
9       96.40
10      50.00
```

Results

```
f1     f9                 
--------------
1      135.58
2      166.3
4       86.46
5      170.33
```

Update:

The result i want is if f1 = f3 and f3 <> sumoff6 then display the output. As you see below for example it still brings up the result if its the same. Look at the first row, which should not be there because f9 = sumoff6.

query:

```
SELECT statement.f1, statement.f9, allocation_2.[f3], allocation_2.sumoff6
FROM allocation_2 LEFT JOIN statement ON allocation_2.[f3]=statement.f1
WHERE statement.f9 <> allocation_2.sumoff6
GROUP BY statement.f1, statement.f9, allocation_2.[f3], allocation_2.sumoff6
ORDER BY statement.f1;
```

Output:

```
f1            f9     f3        sumoff6
--------------------------------------
123456789   135.58  123456789   135.58
111111111   166.3   111111111   66.3
222222222   86.46   222222222   86.46
333333333   170.33  333333333   170.33
444444444   135.58  444444444   35.58
555555555   125.74  555555555   125.74
666666666   73.49   666666666   23.49
777777777   187.99  777777777   87.99
```

Comment: if I'm not misunderstood you. You want to join two tables on f1 column and in matched rows sumoff6 column and f9 column is same then display if they not same then substract them. is it alright? What is your expected result?

Comment: Want to join to tables with unique values in f1 column. I want to find where the f9 and sumoff6 columns differ then subtract those columns that equal f1 but f9/sumoff6 differ

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT statement.f1, iif([allocation_final].sumoff6 = statement.f9, statement.f9, [allocation_final].sumoff6 - statement.f9)
FROM statement LEFT JOIN allocation_final 
ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1]
```

Comment: Hi Marlan. This query still subtracts f9,sumoff6 columns even if allocation_final.f1 <> statement.f1

Comment: Not sure if its because the f1 in both tables dont exactly match row by row since statement table has more rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
switch(t1.[sumoff6] is null,t.[f9] - t.[sumoff6],
t1.[sumoff6] is not null, t.[f9])
FROM statement 
LEFT JOIN allocation_final t ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1] 
LEFT JOIN allocation_final t1 ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final[f1] AND 
statement.[f9] = allocation_final[sumoff6]
```

Pretty straightforward, use two joins, each representing the two conditions and then the case when will subtract when both conditions are met(T1), or just give the first value when only one condition is met(T).

Comment: would this work with access sql view?  because i am getting syntax error (missing operator) in this part of the query. CASE WHEN t1.[sumoff6] is null THEN t.[f9] - t.[sumoff6]
When t1.[sumoff6] is not null THEN t.[f9]
END as [total]

Comment: giving me now a syntax error here: statement.[f1] = allocation_final.[f1] 
LEFT JOIN allocation_final t1 ON statement.[f1] = allocation_final.[f1]

Comment: Hi Matt i got the query to work. I had a question. Its giving me the the discrepancies between the f9 and sumoff6 columns but not accurate. Im thinking this is because there are more rows in the statement column since f1 is not matching in both tables on the SAME row, it thinks the f9 value is missing but its really not. Is there a way to have the query search for the f1 column in the other table to make sure the sumoff6 value is different or not? In other words, the f1 column is present in both tables just in different rows and the query is thinking its missing in the other table.

Comment: all these queries i have been getting help from work only if f1 matches row by row on both tables.

Comment: I have made both tables equal on columns F1 with no duplicate rows. However, i am still getting data with equal rows in my output query even though i put f1=f1 and f9 <> sumoff6. Can someone please help? I am using a Left Join so not sure why i am getting this.

Comment: please see my original post after "update". I have just edited with the result set that you asked for.